# Exposing R and Python scripts via Web Service

Tags: python, r, rest, web-services, production-environment

I am looking to expose a couple of machine learning algorithms as `REST APIs` to integrate them into product loop. These are written in `R` and `Python`, I am trying to achieve the following:

- Should be easy to deploy and run
- Should be able to handle the load on production with high throughput
- Should be easily maintainable as machine learning team won't have much exposure on `API` aspect of the applications

I have had a brief look at the frameworks like `Flask`, `rApache`, `rServe`, `OpenCPU`, `Plumber`, however, these sound like not built for production (maybe I am wrong). I am not familiar with `Python` or `r` so don't know much about concurrency/threading aspect of these, in this case:

- Is this the correct way to expose the service (i.e. with these wrappers)
- Can I write something in Java and call the `r` script from command line or shell? Is that an option or it will create a tight coupling?
- Should I ditch the idea of exposing it as a REST service and look into RPC or cloud functions?

Comment: should be `plumber` not Plumbr. technically, `opencpu` is built on top of `rApache`. very interesting question but prob not the appropriate venue

Comment: I am researching the same thing and found a good discussion here : https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-deploy-Machine-Learning-Models-as-an-API